# SAS Filename URL statement accepting shorter than expected path string

Tags: sas

I have posted on here before regarding the 'Filename URL' statement in SAS and have had some useful information in response about the maximum URL length. I have been working on keeping the string submitted below 2000 characters as advised.

The submission is to Yahoo Finance to pull down a .csv file of stock data. The URL submitted takes the following format:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=TIK1+TIK2+TIK3&f=ab5d6
```

The TIK1 etc in the filepath represents four character stock ticker symbols on the NASDAQ exchange and the the letters after the '&f=' represent various different metrics around stock performance.

Because of SAS returning filename errors as a result of it being too long I have had to trim down the above URL to 200 stock tickers at a time. Much more than about 220 and the code won't run.

What I don't understand though is that filename is less than 1100 characters if you include the stock tickers, all the '+' signds between them and the start and beginning of the URL either side. I should have another 900 characters to play with.

Also, if SAS is submitting this request directly, independant of a web browser, am I still restricted by their URL byte length?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Really not necessary to try to bump 4 hours after sending in the question, particularly when it was submitted on Monday at 4AM Eastern time...

Comment: If you've ended up with multiple accounts and can no longer edit your contributions, please [contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) to get it sorted out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible Yahoo! has a limit of 200; it's very common for APIs to have maximums to keep you from overburdening the server.  [This page](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload) describing the Yahoo Finance APIs (which are at download.finance.yahoo.com, so perhaps slightly different from what you're doing - but perhaps better suited?) suggest in the comments a limit of 50, so 200 is well above that (although that page is 2+ years old).

If you're not already doing this, I would recommend setting up a filename dataset.

```
data have;
infile datalines truncover;
input @1 filen $2000.;
datalines;
http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG+MSFT+AAPL&f=ab5d6
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have;
infile a url filevar=filen lrecl=32767 dlm=',' dsd eov=end end=end;
do until(end);
    input price;
    output;
end;
run;
```

That will make it easier to deal with the multiple filenames, as you can just add lines to the `have` dataset programmatically (it should work with any number of lines, each time sending a new query to Yahoo!).

Answer (score 0):

The problems you are experiencing if no results are being returned are likely problems on the server side rather than on the SAS side.  You will probably find that you do need to limit how many diff stocks/metrics you try and pull in a single attempt.

Alternatives that you might have better luck with are using `proc http` if you have sas 9.2 or later.  Or using a 3rd party tool like `curl`.  Documentation for proc http:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003286808.htm

Curl (google it) is a pretty commonly used program that will send http requests and spit the results to stdout.  You can redirect those results to a file and then have SAS consume the file.  You may also see performance improvements with this approach.  I've done this in the past when the http filename was not enough and it worked well for me.  You can call curl from SAS using the `x` command.